# How can I tell if an application is running as a post/pre-build event or standalone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, post-build-event, pre-build-event

I have an application that is being run as a post-build event:

Project Properties -> Build Events: `call "$(TargetDir)\bin\myApp.exe" "$(ProjectPath)"`

However, sometimes I will run it by itself - sometimes from Visual Studio and sometimes straight from the console.

How can I tell programmatically if an application is being run as a post/pre-build event or standalone (so sometimes there will still be debugger attached, but not always)?

Is there some kind of flag or environment variable I can check?

*Note: I want to check this from within the application that is being run.*

Comment: What do you mean by running as a post/pre-build event? Do you mean is your app running with a debugger attached? Can you give a example?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I should mention that. I'm running with a debugger attached. I'm setting it up as a post or pre-build event through Project Properties -> Build Events.

Comment: Can you please post your build event script? I think its unlikely that the debugger is attached **automatically** to a process started by a build event.

Comment: I think this is an XY problem:  *Why* do you want to know how your application was started?  What difference could it possibly make?

Comment: Could you add a parameter to your build event, and then check for it with GetCommandLineArgs.

Comment: @abelenky When I run as a post-build event, it outputs some stuff that is formatted in a way that Visual Studio understands, but is not particularly human-readable. If I run from the console, I want to format the output differently.

Comment: @WhoIsRich I could add a parameter that tells it how it's being run, but I was wondering if there is another way of doing it. I'd prefer not passing anything else in.

Answer (score -1):

The following will tell you if the debugger is attached.

```
if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: This won't work in my case. I've updated my question.